# Not recieving data from pusher websocket using pusher_client: ^2.0.0

Tags: flutter, websocket, flutter-dependencies, pusher

THIS IS MY CODE

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
// import 'package:pusher_channels_flutter/pusher_channels_flutter.dart';
// import 'package:pusher_channels/pusher_channels.dart';
import 'package:pusher_client/pusher_client.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    main_suma();
  }
  void main_suma() async {
    PusherClient pusher = PusherClient(
        "XXXXXXXXX",
        PusherOptions(
          cluster: "ap2",
              encrypted: true
        ),
        autoConnect: true
    );

    pusher.onConnectionStateChange((state) {
      print("previousState: ${state?.previousState}, currentState: ${state?.currentState}");
    });

    pusher.onConnectionError((error) {
      print("error: ${error?.message}");
    });

// Subscribe to a private channel
    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("mechanic-finder");

// Bind to listen for events called "order-status-updated" sent to "private-orders" channel
    channel.bind("active-requests", (event) {
      print("EVENTS: ${event}");
    });

// Unsubscribe from channel
//     pusher.unsubscribe("mechanic-finder");

// Disconnect from pusher service
//     pusher.disconnect();

  }

// Define your event handlers here (e.g., onEvent, onConnectionStateChange, etc.) as shown in the previous response.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Pusher Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Pusher Example App',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Subscribe'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

THE OUTPUT I'M GETTING IS:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Attaching Geolocator to activity
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Creating service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterLocationService(10561): Creating service.
D/FlutterLocationService(10561): Binding to location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Geolocator foreground service connected
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Initializing Geolocator services
D/FlutterGeolocator(10561): Flutter engine connected. Connected engine count 1
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:60852/PmFPioVtXuM=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/.authenticatio(10561): Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
D/ProfileInstaller(10561): Installing profile for com.example.authentication
W/.authenticatio(10561): JNI critical lock held for 16.411ms on Thread[1,tid=10561,Runnable,Thread*=0xdcbc4610,peer=0x71882b80,"main"]
W/.authenticatio(10561): JNI critical lock held for 27.954ms on Thread[1,tid=10561,Runnable,Thread*=0xdcbc4610,peer=0x71882b80,"main"]
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): Pusher initialized
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): Event stream cancelled.
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): Event stream listening...
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): [BIND] active-requests
I/Choreographer(10561): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/System.err(10561): SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err(10561): SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err(10561): SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): [CONNECTING]
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): [CONNECTED]
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): [PUBLIC] Subscribed: mechanic-finder
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): [ON_EVENT] Channel: mechanic-finder, EventName: pusher:subscription_succeeded,
D/PusherClientPlugin(10561): Data: null, User Id: null
I/flutter (10561): previousState: DISCONNECTED, currentState: CONNECTING
I/flutter (10561): previousState: CONNECTING, currentState: CONNECTED
```

I'm getting Data as null and User Id as null i'm unable to debug based on this output, I have tried different packages still getting the same output. When i first executed the program i got the output  that is the correct non-empty data, after that i'm only receiving this data: null or data: {}.

EDITED:
I'm new to pusher SO FIGURED OUT one thing i.e

- i have to go to the pusher dashboard -> debug console and then press send event only then the event is send to my flutter app.

is there any way to automatically get that? or else i want to know if server updates new data to the pusher it will automatically reflect in my app?